# Wrap each line with a span tag

Tags: templating

Following situation:

I have a inline-block title with a background gradient applied. So in order that the background always starts from the left, each line will have to be spanned by a span tag.

```
Welcome to<br /> 
our site
```

should become this:

```
<span>Welcome to</span><br /> 
<span>our site</span>
```

I've started with this:

```
{{ block.heroTitle|nl2br }}
```

But I'm stuck.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your text

```
{% set text = block.heroTitle|nl2br %}
{% set splited = text|split('<br />')%}
{% for part in splited %}
    <span>{{ part }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

If you need you can use the [trim](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/trim.html) filter as well

```
<span>{{ part|trim }}</span>
```

Comment: That was exactly was I was after! Thanks a lot!